# Convert date format doesn't take effect on self made date string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a rather strange issue here. I have a date string, which I've created partly by myself to incorporate a variable. The problem is, that I'm setting another language settings. In this case, I have to also convert the string to fit the language settings format. I'm using this code:

```
cast(convert(varchar, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@HR as varchar), 2) + ':00:00.000', 120) as datetime)
```

I get the error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.", which is normal if you assign wrong date format before casting.

The problem is, that when I try to convert the personally created date string, it doesn't change its format no matter what format code I set it in. That doesn't change even when I hardcode a number instead of my variable:

```
convert(varchar, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar) + ' 0' + CAST(2 as varchar) + ':00:00.000', 101)
```

results in 2016-09-14 02:00:00.000

For example,

```
convert(varchar, dateadd(Hour, 2, getdate()), 101) as datetime
```

Results in 09/14/2016.

Even though I have a different language setting, isn't SQL server supposed to always recognize the date format in the standard format?

Please give me an advice so I can overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I managed to solve my issue by inserting converted datetime column in a variable before setting bulgarian language. I'm still very interested to know what causes the problem though.

Comment: With `DBCC USEROPTIONS` you can check which dateformat the Database is using. If it was never set before, it changes when you change the Language. But once you set the dateformat like `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` the dateformat will stay the same if you change the language. For further information about this see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me realize my goal (i solved it already), but still doesn't answer my question, which is why convert to certain format number doesn't apply to my string.

Comment: You are right, this was not the answer to your question. But maybe my answer is a bit more helpful to the question. It's all because of the datatype inside the `CONVERT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I may have a soution for the question: Why is the format differently handled in SQL-SERVER when converting.

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

The `STYLE`value only applies for date/time. 
So it's because of the datatype that the output is different.
See following example:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, dateadd(Hour, 2, getdate()), 101) as datetime
```

You get the result:

```
09/14/2016
```

Here your are converting a `datetime` datatype into a `varchar` and the `STYLE`-value with `101` applies for `CONVERT` and the output is converted in that format.

Example 2 is the same but the inner most part is casted into a `varchar` before converting it:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, CAST(dateadd(Hour, 2, getdate()) AS varchar), 101) as datetime
```

The result you get is:

```
Sep 14 2016  4:09PM
```

So because we are trying to convert a `varchar` into a `varchar` the `STYLE`-value doesn't apply for the conversion.

That is also why the first query is handled diffrent then the other:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar) + ' 0' + CAST(2 as varchar) + ':00:00.000', 101)
```

Here you cast into `varchar` **cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar)** before converting. So the `STYLE`-value is not applying because it's not from datatype date/time.

I hope it made it a bit clear. Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 1):

When you use convert to format the datetime, you can pass a style number to it.
Looky [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for those numbers.

The query below converts custom created datetimes to the 126 (ISO8601) format.

```sql
declare @d int = 2;

SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar,
        CONVERT(datetime,
                CONCAT(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),' ',@d,':0')
                )
         ,126) AS MyDateStamp1,
CONVERT(varchar,
        CONVERT(datetime,
                CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),102)+' '+convert(varchar,@d)+':0'
                )
         ,126) AS MyDateStamp2;
```

The FORMAT & CONCAT functions can be used in SQL Server 2012 and beyond.
But if you have an earlier version then CONVERT should work instead.

Comment: I already have a format style number in my querries. It doesn't apply (at least not correctly), that's the whole point of my question. Anyway, you were very helpful to remind me for the FORMAT function.

Comment: Your problem was that you tried to convert a varchar to a varchar in a format.  `select convert(varchar,'2001-01-01 01:01:00',101)` doesn't raise an error but it's pointless.  While in the answer a varchar is converted to a datetime, and then the datetime is converted to a varchar in a certain format.

Answer (score 1):

Additional tip: 
If you're using the CONVERT solution above, note that 

"convert(varchar, CAST(dateadd(Hour, 2, getdate()) AS varchar), 101)" 
calls for you to set datatype to varchar.

I just came across code 

"Convert(date,ML.StartDate,101)" 

and since style 101 is mm/dd/yyyy, and the output was yyyy-mm-dd, I knew something was wrong.  By changing the code to

 "Convert(varchar,ML.StartDate,101)" 

the proper date style was displayed in the result set.